# how to preserve image quality after adding it to a jasperreport(created in iReport)?

Tags: java, image, jasper-reports, ireport

i've been struggling since 72hours with an image issue.anytime i add an image to ireport 4.6 the image is always blur and that  blur image appears on the pdf generated by the jasperreport after running it. after googling i was pointed to the dpi of the image. i've tried increasing the dpi of the image but it seems the same.i've tried save a svg version of the image from an online converter and went through the trouble of adding a .svg version of the image.

am wondering if there is trick to it? can anyone shed some light? looking at my timeline am officially one day late on this.

thanks for reading this and helping out

Comment: What's the original dpi of the image? I am having a similar problem. My logo is a jpg, 300 dpi. Curious to see what others recommend.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to jasperreports.properties. I find it makes much sharper reports.

```
net.sf.jasperreports.image.dpi=300
```

Comment: I've added that to both properties for ireport and jasperreports.properties in my classpath before posting here.wasn't affecting it. thanks

Comment: Are you certain that it wasn't affected? If it wasn't affected, then you're somehow not doing it correctly. If it was affected but that's not sufficient for your needs... then that's a different problem. Maybe it would help to attach a simple report with just one sample image to show the issue. Then others can test it.

Comment: @mdahlman  i have the same problem. My image is about 96dpi, and no matter if i set net.sf.jasperreports.image.dpi=300 or to net.sf.jasperreports.image.dpi=96, the same blur appears in the report.

Answer (score 0):

JRAbstractSvgRenderer hope this class may help you.

You can extends this class. and  use it as parameter input.